# Capturing a string without escape sequence

Tags: python, regex, list

So I'm setting out on my coding journey by completing hackerrank problems, and I'm stuck in a step. I will not explain the problem, but will only try to explain the step I'm stuck in.

So I have a list of strings, all of them except for the last one have the "\r" escape sequence, as a string.

I try to remove the \r manually using re but fail to do so.
Please help me out!

(**Edit**: I actually used re.sub, I just typed it wrong)

Here is the code:

```
`l = ['S;V;iPad\r', 'C;M;mouse pad\r', 'C;C;code swarm\r', 'S;C;OrangeHighlighter']
 pattern= re.compile("""\\[r]""")
 l_new = [pattern.sub(i,'') for i in l] `
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `re.sub()` method:

```py
import re

l = ['S;V;iPad\r', 'C;M;mouse pad\r', 'C;C;code swarm\r', 'S;C;OrangeHighlighter']
l_new = [re.sub(r'\r', '', i) for i in l]
print(l_new)
```

This will remove all occurrences of the `\r` escape sequence.

Comment: Hi, the solution seems to be working now! Is there something I did wrong? I did use the sub method in my solution. Also thank you!

Comment: Oh my god, I messed up the syntax. Got to know where I went wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest not using the `re` module, and instead using the more pythonic approach of using `[i.replace('\r','')for i in l]`.

Comment: Hi, this solution is working perfectly fine! Thank you. But why am I not able to do it through re? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: `re` is overkill for this, because all you need to do is remove a string. Regex isn't the right tool for the job here, it's for matching complex patterns and performing operations on them.